# Cannot get "Localization native development region" works in IOS6

Tags: ios6, localization

I have an IOS app that has 2 targets. 1 target is for Turkish store, and the other one is world wide.

One of the plist, I choose Localization native development region as "en". In the other one, I choose "tr".

[image]

In IOS7, everything is fine. But IOS6 doesn't understand which localization should be applied.

What is the right way to do this?